# dispatch.yaml not working for task queue when defaulting production environment

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-module

I started teasing apart an app into two modules and successfully have the app running on App Engine. I can verify the new configuration by using the module/version specific URLs to drive traffic and see requests and task queue events processed without error.

For example, using - http://micro-services.msn-transit-api.appspot.com - correctly drives traffic to the new, non-default version.

However, when I ***update the default version in the GAE console***, requests that should be dispatched to a new module are not routing correctly. They are dispatched to the default module and fail since the endpoints have moved.

It's as if dispatch.yaml isn't activated.

Default App yaml file :

```
application: msn-transit-api
module: default
version: micro-services
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 3
```

New module yaml file :

```
application: msn-transit-api
module: stats-and-maps
version: micro-services
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
instance_class: B1
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1

handlers:

# map apps
- url: /map(.*)
  script: stats_and_maps.maps.map.app

# stats task
- url: /stats/new/.*
  script: stats_and_maps.stats.stathat.application
```

Dispatch yaml :

```
dispatch:
  - url: "*/map*"
    module: stats-and-maps

  - url: "*/stats/*"
    module: stats-and-maps
```

***It's worth noting that the endpoints that are failing are getting hit by jobs in the Task Queue.***

Why would defaulting the version on GAE change its behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it buried in the Task Queue documentation. :(

Queues have a "target" configuration directive. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue?hl=en#Python_Queue_definitions) has this nugget :

> If target is unspecified, then tasks are invoked on the same version
>   of the application where they were enqueued

I believe they are using "version" and "module" interchangeably in this context.

This also allows me to do away with the dispatch.yaml file for those routes!